# F# collection initializer syntax

Tags: f#, inline

What is the [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax in F#? In C# you can write something like:

```
new Dictionary<string, int>() {
    {"One", 1},
    {"two", 2}}
```

How do I do the same thing in F#? I suppose i could roll my own syntax, but seems like there should be a built-in or standard one already.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As Jared says, there is no built-in support for this for arbitrary collections.  However, the C# code is just syntactic sugar for `Add` method calls, so you could translate it to:

```
let coll = MyCollectionType()
["One", 1; "Two", 2] |> Seq.iter coll.Add
```

If you want to get fancy, you could create an `inline` definition to streamline this even further:

```
let inline initCollection s =
  let coll = new ^t()
  Seq.iter (fun (k,v) -> (^t : (member Add : 'a * 'b -> unit) coll, k, v)) s
  coll

let d:System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_> = initCollection ["One",1; "Two",2]
```

Comment: A (nit-picky) style preference: I would put this in a `Collection` module and name it `init`, since `Collection.init [1; 2; 3]` reads nicely.

Comment: @Daniel - good point.  Also note that in contrast to C#'s syntactic sugar, this function is arity-specific (that is, it only works on `Add` methods taking two arguments) and you'd need to create another function for initializing collections which use a unary `Add` method (as in your example usage).

Answer (score 83):

To elaborate a bit on collection initialization in F#, here are a few examples:

**read-only dictionary**

```
dict [ (1, "a"); (2, "b"); (3, "c") ]
```

**seq (IEnumerable<T>)**

```
seq { 0 .. 99 }
```

**list**

```
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

**set**

```
set [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

**array**

```
[| 1; 2; 3; 4; 5 |]
```

Comment: Maybe `dict <| seq { (1, "a"); (2, "b"); (3, "c") }` and `set <| seq {1; 2; 3; 4; 5}` are more efficient then?

Answer (score 15):

I don't believe F# has an explicit collection initializer syntax.  However it's usually very easy to initialize F# collections.  For example

```
let map = [ ("One", 1); ("Two", 2) ] |> Map.ofSeq
```

Getting to BCL collections is usually a bit more difficult because they don't always have the handy conversion functions.  `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` works though because you can use the LINQ method

```
let map = 
  let list = [ ("One", 1); ("Two", 2) ] 
  System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(list, fst, snd)
```

Comment: I'm wanting to initialize other C# collection objects such as MongoDB Bson objects.

Comment: @srparish I'm unfamiliar with those objects. Can you link us to an API?

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-CreateanewdocumentanduseC%23%27scollectioninitializersyntax%28recommended%29

Comment: The ToDictionary conversion can be simplified: `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(list, fst, snd)`

Comment: If an immutable `IDictionary<K, V>` will suffice, you can simply prefix your list with `dict`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the same :

```
open System.Collections.Generic

Dictionary<int, string>(dict [ (1, "a"); (2, "b"); (3, "c") ])
```

Cheers.

Comment: Of course you mean `Dictionary<int, string>`. That syntax isn't bad though!

Answer (score 2):

The lack of a collection initializer is annoying for some XAML-centric APIs like Workflow 4.0 which rely on collection initializers instead of ctors, e.g.

```
new Sequence { Activities = { WriteLine { Text = "In the sequence!" } } };
```

In such cases, imperative .Add() is awkward because the value is *conceptually* declarative even though it's technically mutable/imperative. However, there's no common base class for the set of all activities which declare an Activities child: the "Activities" member is a *pattern* and not an interface, so you can't just write a normal helper function which adds children to any activity. Fortunately, F# member constraints come to the rescue.

In order to write this:

```
Sequence() |> add [Sequence(DisplayName="InnerSeq"); WriteLine(Text = InArgument<_>("In the sequence!"))]
```

You first need to define an inline helper function called "add":

```
let inline add (children: Activity seq) =
    let inline doAdd (activity: ^Activity) : ^Activity when ^Activity : (member get_Activities : unit -> Activity Collection) =
        let collection = (^Activity : (member get_Activities : unit -> Activity Collection) (activity))
        for child in children do
            collection.Add(child)
        activity
    doAdd
```

This still isn't quite as nice as the C# syntax but at least it's still declarative. IMHO this is not so much as a fault with F# as with collection-initializer-centric APIs, but at least F# allows a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the C# collection initializer syntax is syntactic sugar for calling `.Add` and that implies a mutable collection - I'm not sure you'll see any such syntax in F#. It's initialize all in one go as per JaredPar's answer, or do it manually.